# How do I helm search a specific repo?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I don't want to fuzzy search the entire chart name including the local repo name I want to explicitly search in a specific repo.

I have private repos:

```
> helm repo list

NAME    URL
dev     https://me.jfrog.io/artifactory/helm-dev
prod    https://me.jfrog.io/artifactory/helm-prod
```

How can I do this (this arg does not exist `--repo-name=dev`):

```
helm search repo --repo-name=dev --devel -l
```

Or even this:

```
helm search repo --repo-url=https://me.jfrog.io/artifactory/helm-dev --devel -l
```

Comment: i don't get it. Is the result not fit you when you run "helm search repo dev"

Comment: no. That does a full text search and returns everything that includes the string `dev` . For example: `prod/stable/sapho 0.2.3 micro application development and integration...`

Comment: so, after all, "grep" can help you minimize your result if you exactly know what you search: "helm search repo dev | grep blabla", does it?

Comment: I have the same question ... how do I run `helm search` against a specific repo that's I've added?

Answer (score 0):

There's this nugget from Helm v2 `--help`, which will restrict matches to an exact repo and chart:

```
To look for charts with a particular name (such as stable/mysql), try
searching using vertical tabs (\v). Vertical tabs are used as the delimiter
between search fields. For example:

    helm search --regexp '\vstable/mysql\v'
```

This still works in Helm v3 (despite not being mentioned in the docs), so in your case substitute in `dev`/`prod` as needed:

```
helm search repo --regexp "\vdev/my-chart\v"
```

Comment: Thats a neat feature, but it's essentially the same thing as grep. Its clear helm doesn't support this. The feature I'm looking for is not having to do any greping or parsing and just looking in a specific repo.